# Trying to map a struct to my exposed API struct

Tags: go

I am writing mapping functions that map my internal models to those that I will expose in my API.

How do I map the Locations property.  Do I range over them? Do I have to init the UserApi locations first?

I little confused on how to best do this without having any nil exceptions etc.

```
func mapUserToApi(user User) UserApi {
  api := &UserApi{
     Id: user.Id,
     ..
     ..
  }

  for index, location := range user.Locations {
    /// ????????????
  }

  return api
}

func mapLocationToApi(location Locatio) LocationApi {
  ..
}


type User struct {
  Id int

  Locations []Location
}

type UserApi struct {
  Id int

  Locations []LocationApi
}
```

Comment: Do you really need this mapping? The most idiomatic way to expose functionality in Go would be to use interfaces to only expose the public contract of your objects without leaking implementation details.

Comment: Yes I do, I have to change the shape of the objects.

Comment: @SirDarius For example, there is struct with a collection that has another collection.  I need to remove 1 layer of the collections and merge some fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate first then loop for range

```
func mapUserToApi(user User) UserApi {
  api := &UserApi{
     Id: user.Id,
     Locations: make([]LocationApi, len(user.Locations), len(user.Locations)),
  }

  for index, location := range user.Locations {
    api.Locations[index] = mapLocationToApi(location)
  }

  return api
}
```

Comment: Why do you do len() 2 times? one is for the size of the array, the other?

Comment: Capacity. Slice has length and capacity

Answer (score 0):

`range` will work fine for what you want to do. The code below is non-specific and can be generalized to your use case.

```
func mapLocationsToModifiedLocations(user User) []ModifiedLocation {
    // initialize a new slice with the type of your API-appropriate output
    // and a length of zero
    var output := make([]ModifiedLocation, 0)

    // iterate over your input data
    for _, element := range user.Locations {
        // use append to automatically re-size the output array as needed
        output = append(output, modifyLocation(location))
    }

    return output
}
```